# Tmux status bar question

Tags: terminal, osx, tmux, terminal-multiplexer

I'm fairly new to tmux and to truly master and learn it, I decided to make myself a fresh .tmux.conf

I was wondering, though, if it's possible to hide a path in the status bar.

For example, I have this in my tmux.conf:

```
setw -g window-status-format '#I #10W'
setw -g window-status-current-format '#[fg=red][#I:#10W]#F'
```

Now, let's use my window as an example.

In one window, I have macvim running. The tmux status bar changes to "[1:mvim]*". That's exactly what I want. But I have another pane inside that window running ttytter. When I switch to it, tmux doesn't change the name to "1:[ttytter]*"

Also, in another window, I have opened a directory with a long path name. tmux changes the status bar to "[1:...long/path]*". I've seen people run their tmux and it only says "zsh" for them. How can I have that too? I don't want the full path name inside my status bar.

I'm running tmux on OS X if that helps.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3):

I answered my own question.

I'm really happy about this since I've been trying to get it like that and it was such a simple fix.

I was actually using prezto, the zsh framework and in my ~/.zpreztorc, I forgot I set it to autotitle my terminal tabs/windows.

So I changed:
    zstyle 'prezto:module:terminal' auto-title 'yes'
to
    zstyle 'prezto:module:terminal' auto-title 'no'

and the problem goes away. There are a lot of options in the modules you can set as well. If anyone is running prezto, I recommend reading the terminal module readme and researching what the module actually does.

Comment: I met this issue also. This (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34596827/tmux-window-namew-shows-long-path-in-windows-status-format) is my question. But I don't using zsh and zstyle. I'm using bash. Can you help me for that?